# Iphone Testing App on Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

Is it possible to test your iPhone app on Xcode, not on the simulator, but on your actual phone before releasing it on the app store.

Comment: please go thru [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html)

Comment: If u have the code for the app, then yes, else no!!!

Comment: Is this really a question? Doesn't it seem likely that most apps are tested on real devices before being submitted to the App Store?

Comment: I haven't tried for a while, but it used to just be a question of connecting your phone to the computer and selecting it as the target in XCode.

Comment: So if you have the Xcode project ready to go, can you run it on the phone?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you must have an apple developer account which is $99 a year. Once you have it, you can hook it up to xcode and you will be allowed to run apps on your phone

https://developer.apple.com/programs/

Update: according to @seb, the paid account is no longer needed for personal testing, which seems to be backed up here:

https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/
A good resource for starting developers. I'd look at the above link for information on the different programs.

Comment: Okay, thank you for being concise and clear

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can test your app on iPhone. You need an [Apple developer account](https://idmsa.apple.com/IDMSWebAuth/login?&appIdKey=891bd3417a7776362562d2197f89480a8547b108fd934911bcbea0110d07f757&path=%2F%2Fmembercenter%2Findex.action). It costs $99 per year. Once you have it, you can test your app on your iPhone device and upload the app to [itunesconnect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/itc/static/login?view=1&path=%2FWebObjects%2FiTunesConnect.woa%3F). Go through Apple's Documentation below.

[Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html)

Answer (score 0):

That's not correct. With the new Xcode **edit: 7** (not Xcode 9) it is possible to test your code directly on your device without having a developer account.

Comment: Can someone verify this?

Comment: Just trust me or google it

Comment: That was the big news on the last WWDC. No need to verify. Only problem is that the free developer accounts are well hidden on Apple's website. They probably think if you are not clever enough to find it, then you shouldn't be trying to write iOS apps :-)